# How to update label widget within container widget every second

Tags: pyqt

So I have a GUI that contains widgets that looks up in a database for the value of a variable and displays the variable name and current value in the same fashion as a kv pair using two `QLabel` next to each other and called them a `DisplayItemWidget`. I then stacked a bunch of these `DisplayItemWidget` in another widget which I called a `CellContainerWidget` and I had a bunch of those in a grid so that I can keep track of multiple groupings of variables as they change. The database that all the widgets query from is constantly being updated and I want my GUI to update the individual `DisplayItemWidgets` to update every second. But I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using a QTimer to send timer events to the `MainWindow` but that's not working. So I was wondering what's the architecture supposed to be to have inner, inner widgets update every second.

A stripped down version of my code is here:

```
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    import sys
    import random

    def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        db = Database()

        ########## instantiate fake data
        cell_list = []
        taglist = ['ground_tlm', 'state_tlm']
        counter = 0
        for tag in taglist:
            display_list = []
            display_name = tag.split('_')[0] + ' stuff'
            for i in range(int((random.random()*5)+1)):
                db.update([tag, 'var-%i' % i, 'float', str(random.random())])
                widget = DisplayItemWidget(tag, 'var-%i' % i, db)
                display_list.append(widget)
            ccw = CellContainerWidget(display_list, display_name, counter, 0)
            counter += 1
            cell_list.append(ccw)

        taglist = ['random_tlm', 'up_tlm']
        counter = 0
        for tag in taglist:
            display_list = []
            display_name = tag.split('_')[0] + ' stuff'
            for i in range(int((random.random()*5)+1)):
                db.update([tag, 'var-%i' % i, 'float', str(random.random())])
                widget = DisplayItemWidget(tag, 'var-%i' % i, db)
                display_list.append(widget)
            ccw = CellContainerWidget(display_list, display_name, counter, 1)
            counter += 1
            cell_list.append(ccw)
        ##########

        mw = MainWindow(cell_list, db)
        mw.show()
        timer = QBasicTimer()
        timer.start(500, mw)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


    class DisplayItemWidget(QWidget):

        def __init__(self, tag, var_name, db):
            super(DisplayItemWidget, self).__init__()
            self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
            self.label1 = QLabel()
            self.label2 = QLabel()
            self.tag = tag
            self.var_name = var_name
            self.db = db
            self.init_ui()

        def init_ui(self):
            self.label1.setText(self.tag + ': ' + self.var_name)

            self.label1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.label1)

            val = self.db.get_val(self.tag, self.var_name)
            if val is not None:
                self.label2.setText(val)
                self.label2.setText(val)
            self.label2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)

            self.layout.setSpacing(10)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)
            self.setWindowTitle("Display Item Widget")

        def update_value(self):
            val = self.db.get_val(self.tag, self.var_name)
            if val is not None:
                self.label2.setText(val)


    class CellContainerWidget(QWidget):

        def __init__(self, display_list, cell_name, col_index, row_index):
            super(CellContainerWidget, self).__init__()
            self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.cell_name_label = QLabel()
            self.cell_name_label.setText(cell_name)
            self.display_list = display_list
            self.col_index = col_index
            self.row_index = row_index
            self.init_ui()

        def init_ui(self):
            self.cell_name_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.cell_name_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cell_name_label)

            for widget in self.display_list:
                widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
                self.layout.addWidget(widget)

            self.layout.setSpacing(0)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)
            self.setWindowTitle("Cell Item Widget")

        def get_widgets(self):
            return self.display_list


    class MainWindow(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, cell_list, db):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
            self.layout = QGridLayout()
            self.cell_list = cell_list
            self.db = db
            self.init_ui()

        def init_ui(self):
            for cell in self.cell_list:
                cell.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
                self.layout.addWidget(cell, cell.col_index, cell.row_index)

            self.layout.setSpacing(0)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)
            self.setWindowTitle("Main Window Widget")

        def update_gui(self, event):

            ########## Mock out update to first column
            print self.db.print_contents()
            taglist = ['ground_tlm', 'state_tlm']
            for tag in taglist:
                for i in range(int((random.random()*5)+1)):
                    self.db.update([tag, 'var-%i' % i, 'float', str(random.random())])
            ##########

            for cell in self.cell_list:
                for widget in cell.get_widgets():
                    widget.update_value()


    class Database():
        def __init__(self):
            self.telemetry_types = {
                'state_tlm': {'var-1': ('int', '0'), }  # Example of how this will be populated
            }

        def get_var_table(self, tlm_type):
            return self.telemetry_types.get(tlm_type, None)

        def update(self, parsed_data):
            tlm_type, var_name, var_type, datum = parsed_data
            if tlm_type in self.telemetry_types:
                    self.telemetry_types[tlm_type][var_name] = (var_type, datum)
            else:
                self.telemetry_types[tlm_type] = {
                    var_name: (var_type, datum),
                }

        def get_val(self, tlm_type, var_name):
            if tlm_type in self.telemetry_types:
                if var_name in self.telemetry_types[tlm_type]:
                    return self.telemetry_types[tlm_type][var_name][1]
                else:
                    return None
            else:
                return None

        def print_contents(self):
            print self.telemetry_types

        def get_keys(self):
            return self.telemetry_types.keys()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

which only updates once and then nevermore. And the event timer isn't even being registered by the mw. I feel like I'm missing something fundamentally wrong with how I laid things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't instantiating your Timer correctly.

Currently, you are passing your object `mw` to the `QBasicTimer`, but this object has not been written to handle Timer events. In short, it doesn't know that it should call `update_gui` (and why would it? That is a method you created and named arbitrarily!)

Instead, I would recommend constructing a timer as follows, using the `QTimer` class rather than the `QBasicTimer`:

```
timer = QTimer(mw)
timer.timeout.connect(mw.update_gui)
timer.start(500)
```

This creates a `QTimer`, connects the `timeout` signal to the `update_gui` slot and starts the timer (with a timeout of 500 ms).

Note you will also need to change the signature of `MainWindow.update_gui` to not include the `event` variable. So it should look like `def update_gui(self):`

Comment: That makes sense. The reason I did it that way was because I saw an example that used a timer event to update a datetime widget. But yeah I understand that that doesn't make any sense to do it like that.  Thank you.